# Azure ML and r scripts

Tags: r, azure-machine-learning-service

I have dataframe with columns

```
date    open    high    low     close   adjclose    volume
```

I want to add one more column named "result"(1 if close > open, 0 if close < open)

I do

```
# Map 1-based optional input ports to variables
data <- maml.mapInputPort(1) # class: data.frame



# calculate pass/fail
data$result <- as.factor(sapply(data$close,function(res) 
    if (res - data$open >= 0) '1' else '0'))

# Select data.frame to be sent to the output Dataset port
maml.mapOutputPort("data");
```

But I have only 1 in result. Where is the problem?

Comment: Your pass/fail step could be made more efficient with `data$result <-  with(data, factor(as.integer(close - open  >= 0)))`  .  In your code, it is subtracting each value of 'close' from the whole 'open column, which will result in a logical output with `length` equal to the nrow of data.  `if/else` would take only an expression returning single TRUE/FALSE.  so, it is anyway not going to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `if/else` can return only a single TRUE/FALSE and is not vectorized for length > 1.  It may be suitable to use `ifelse` (but that is also not required and would be less efficient compared to direct coersion of logical vector to binary (`as.integer`).   In the OP's code, the 'close' column elements are looped  (`sapply`) and subtracted from the whole 'open' column.  The intention might be to do elementwise subtraction.  In that case, `-` between the columns is much cleaner and efficient (as these operations are vectorized)

```
data$result <- with(data, factor(as.integer((close - open) >= 0)))
```

In the above, we get the difference between the columns ('close', 'open'), check if it is greater than or equal to 0 (returns logical vector), convert it to binary (`as.integer` - TRUE -> 1, FALSE -> 0) and then change it to `factor` type (if needed)